# jquery error in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, runtime-error

I am doing a tutorial with Asp.net Mvc. And yesterday I updated my jquery from NuGet Packages. Today I also clean the history of my IE broswer. However, it said the error as following:

```
Unhandled exception at line 5, column 388 in      http://localhost:52372/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

0x800a03f6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid character
```

Do I need to modify something after updating. I thought it is auto modified.

Thanks

Comment: you need to show some code, for us to be able to help.

Comment: I woder if you're referencing two different versions of jquery or any other library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a conflict between some of the jQuery code/plugins you're using.  Take a look at [this post](http://aeronaught.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-on-form-submission-using-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/).  Essentially, a recent version of jQuery and a recent version of the jQuery unobtrusive validation plugin conflict with each other.

When I encountered this issue I was able to overcome it by simply upgrading to the latest `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` (which at the time was 2.0.30116.0).

Comment: Hi, I solved it by delete the updated jquery as well as dependencies. As manully import the jquery script file.